# How is the Chebyshev's inequality used in this instance?

Tags: probability, statistics, graph-theory, estimation

I'm looking at the following situation, where the quantity $|E'|$ is estimated, given parameters $\epsilon, \delta_1, n,p, \text{and } r$.

> - $\mathbb{E}\left[\left|E^{\prime}\right|\right]=e(H) p=\left(1 \pm \delta_{1}\right) \frac{\varepsilon n}{r}$
> - $\operatorname{Var}\left(\left|E^{\prime}\right|\right)=e(H) p(1-p) \leq \mathbb{E}\left[\left|E^{\prime}\right|\right]=o\left(\mathbb{E}\left[\left|E^{\prime}\right|\right]^{2}\right)$
> - $\therefore$ Chebyshev $\Rightarrow$ with high probability, $\left|E^{\prime}\right|=\left(1 \pm 2 \delta_{1}\right) \frac{\varepsilon n}{r}$

Can I have an elaboration of the last claim?

**Edit:** the notations are used in the context of a graph-theoretical lemma:

[image]

Comment: can you please elaborate the meaning of notations you use, if possible?

Comment: I've just added some more details. Hope it makes the question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that, with high probability, $|E^{\prime}| = (1 \pm 2 \delta_{1}) \frac{\varepsilon n}{r}$.  Equivalently,
$$\left||E^{\prime}| - \frac{\varepsilon n}{r} \right| \leq \frac{2\delta_1 \varepsilon n}{r}. \tag{1}\label{eq:1}$$
Because $\mathbb{E}\bigl[|E^{\prime}|\bigr] = (1 \pm \delta_{1}) \frac{\varepsilon n}{r}$, it is enough to show that
$$\bigl||E^{\prime}| - \mathbb{E}\bigl[|E^{\prime}|\bigr] \bigr| \leq \frac{\delta_1 \varepsilon n}{r}.$$

We are given that $\operatorname{Var}\bigl(|E^{\prime}|\bigr) = o\Bigl(\mathbb{E}\bigl[|E^{\prime}|\bigr]^{2}\Bigr) = o(n^2)$.  So, by Chebyshev's Inequality,
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\bigl||E^{\prime}| - \mathbb{E}\bigl[|E^{\prime}|\bigr] \bigr| > \frac{\delta_1 \varepsilon n}{r}\right) \leq \frac{\operatorname{Var}\bigl(|E^{\prime}|\bigr)}{(\delta_1 \varepsilon n / r)^2} = o(1).$$
Thus, \eqref{eq:1} holds with high probability, as claimed.